# Different version of a nuget package is being installed and referenced during build to the project references and packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rabbitmq, nuget, teamcity

On our build server I have a solution where all projects reference version 3.6 of the rabbit client tools Nuget package. However when I build the solution on the build server it seems to be downloading version 4.0.2 of the rabbit client tools. Even though there is no reference to this dll either in my code, or the easynetq library that I'm also using alongside this as far as I can tell.

I've tried:

- Clearing the nuget cache on the server
- Cleaning the checkout directories
- Changing the rabbit client nuget version
- Checked the assembly binding versions in the app.config.

All are correct before the build occurs.

As an aside, I don't know if this will make much difference, but the assembly redirects in the app and web configs for my apps are also being switched to 4, even though my local code is 3.6.5.

Also, this does seem to build fine through visual studio 2015 so I'm assuming this must be something that can get left behind on the server somewhere to do with Nuget.

Packages.Config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EasyNetQ" version="0.62.1.445" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EasyNetQ.Management.Client" version="0.51.1.105" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="GuerrillaNtp" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="mongocsharpdriver" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="OctoPack" version="3.0.45" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="RabbitMQ.Client" version="3.6.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Topshelf" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Please post your packages.config file.

Comment: done @granadaCoder

Comment: Are you saying that you get a subfolder in the "packages" directory called ".\packages\RabbitMQ.Client.4.0.2" ( ~instead of ".\packages\RabbitMQ.Client.3.6.5").... and/or that your build logs refer to "4.0.2" ?

Comment: I get both. The 4.0.2 folder seems to appear during the build at some point, and the build seems to then reference the 4.0.2 folder. @granadaCoder

Comment: Do this on the build server.  Delete all the subfolders under ".\packages" and run a manual nuget restore on just the packages.config file.  like this:   nuget.exe restore  .\packages.config -PackagesDirectory .\MyPackages

Comment: You can get the command line nuget.exe here : https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

Comment: @granadaCoder this is where it gets interesting... if I do it before the build I get 3.6.5, after the build and I get 4.0.2

Comment: The actual packages.config seems to change during the build

Comment: That is some serious voodoo.  At least you got closer to the issue.  I tried your packages.config here and didn't have any issues........so I don't know.  I use the "manual pull packages.config" trick when I have voodoo issues, but never heard of that one before.

Comment: @granadaCoder well I'm not sure if to laugh or cry... TeamCity's nuget build step includes an "Update Packages" option, which I just found, and was switched on. At least its explained :). Oddly it doesn't seem to log that its doing that in the build logs.

Comment: @granada coder thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm going to add an answer...just so this issue can be properly closed.....and not keep showing up in SOF "not answered" queries.

Comment: @granadaCoder, you might want to add a note about what the OP found about TeamCity in your answer.

Comment: If the OP tags the question with TeamCity, then I will do so.  Then again, I'm not really sure what the rules of etiquette are for hind-sight answers.  (Since my answer/comments helped lead him to the root of the issue)

Comment: @granadaCoder I've done both for you

Comment: Go Team! (But not Team-City)  ;)  #seriousVoodooExplained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running a "manual nuget restore" on the build server....just to see if that is working correctly.  Temporarily push it to a different "packages" directory.  I've used "MyPackages" here.

```
nuget.exe restore .\packages.config -PackagesDirectory .\MyPackages
```

You can get the command line nuget.exe from here:

https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

The key here will be:

Which subfolders are you getting?

> ".\MyPackages\RabbitMQ.Client.4.0.2"

and/or

> ".\MyPackages\RabbitMQ.Client.3.6.5"

If the "manual nuget restore" is working correctly
(which in this case would be only getting the subfolder ".\MyPackages\RabbitMQ.Client.3.6.5"), then there is something outside of the normal nuget workflow that is happening during your build.

**OP ANSWER EDIT**
This line of investigation didn't fully solve the issue but did point to something else changing the packages file whilst the build was running. It ended up being TeamCity having an Auto Update feature in its nuget package restore, which wasn't being logged.